# How can I make Hover overlay text fixed to an Image

Tags: html, css

This is the portion of my HTML: I want to have to the text fixed to an image and not disappear when I stop hovering on the text.

```css
.overlay1 {
   position: relative; 
  bottom: 0; 
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Black see-through */
  color: #f1f1f1; 
  width: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity:0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

/*Test hover*/
.container1:hover .overlay1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container1">

                    <a href="/content/gallery">
                     <div class="columny">
                        <div class="row1">
                            <img src="sites/chau.ac.zm/themes/chau/images/AF.jpg" alt="Snow" class="image" style="width:100%">
                              <!--  <div class="overlay1"> -->
                                    <div class="overlay1">Gallery</div>
                              <!--  </div> -->
                             </div>
                          </div>
                      </a>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, you want `div.overlay1` to

1. be invisible initially
2. be visible on hover over `div.container1`
3. stay visible even if you hover out of `div.container1`

You cannot achieve 3. without using JavaScript.
I suggest this code:

```css
/* You need this container to limit the .overlay1 position */
.img-container {
    position: relative;
}

.overlay1 {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; 
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Black see-through */
    color: #f1f1f1; 
    width: 100%;
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity:0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

/*Test hover - change :hover to class .visible */
.container1.visible .overlay1 {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1" class="container1">
    <a href="/content/gallery">
        <div class="columny">
            <div class="row1">
                <div class="img-container">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1462899006636-339e08d1844e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&h=150&q=80" alt="Snow" class="image" style="width:100%">
                    <!--  <div class="overlay1"> -->
                    <div class="overlay1">Gallery</div>
                    <!--  </div> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<script>
    // get element
    var container1 = document.getElementById("container1");
    // add hover event function
    container1.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        container1.className = "container1 visible";
    });
</script>
```

Comment: 3.stay visible even if you hover out of div.container1
 I want this effect.  I have included the JS but did not work. I also tried to use "overlay1 visible " it did not work. or is there a way I can achieve the same result I want without using "hover" property in CSS

Comment: Is there any error message in the browser console? I updated the code to work in older browsers. But still you might want to use jQuery for cross and legacy browser support.

Answer (score 0):

See the solution if it works!

Just one question:
If you need a text to be fixed to an image, then why are you using hover?

```css
.overlay1 {
   position: absolute;  
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Black see-through */
  color: #f1f1f1; 
  width: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity:1;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  right:-20px;
  top:50%;
}
.row1{
  position:relative;
  width:500px;  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">

                    <a href="/content/gallery">
                     <div class="columny">
                        <div class="row1">
                            <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/field-spring-flowers-sunlight-450w-377208970.jpg" alt="" />
                              <!--  <div class="overlay1"> -->
                                    <div class="overlay1">Gallery</div>
                              <!--  </div> -->
                             </div>
                          </div>
                      </a>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove class from gallery div 
`<div class="overlay1">Gallery</div>` remove the class and use  without any "overlay1"class